# Product is undefined in fake store API in console in Next Js inside getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js

Product is undefined in fake store API in the console in Next Js inside getServerSideProps

console.log(product) is undefined. I have debugged it using a console but it still shows undefined

```
import axios from "axios";
import Products from "./Products";

const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
  console.log(product);
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Products product={product} />
    </div>
  );
};


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res =await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
  const product = await res.json();
  
  return {
    props: {
      product: product,
    },
  };
}

      export default ProductCard
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use axios, you do not use `res.json()`.

You can correct it as follows.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { data } =await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");

  
  return {
    props: {
      product: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Problem still exists

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work for you. It works as expected here -> https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-waterfall-1dbriu?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: make sure ProductCard is a page, and not a component. getServerSideProps only work in page.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `getServerSideProps` in component.So the final answer is that `getServerSideProps` works only in pages, not in components